# How to display jquery dialog on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have a jquery pop up with confirmation info when clicking on a specific link in my navigation menu.I have the code below, but the popup does not appear, but the info on the popup display on the page among other page content.

**HTML Link**

`<li><a href="#" id="order" target="_blank">Order </a></li>`

**Dialog content**

```
<div id="dialog-confirm"> 
<div class="message">UI Content goes here</div> 
<div class="buttons"> 
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
 <script>
 $( function() {
 $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
   $( "#order").click({  
  resizable: true,
  height: "auto",
  width: 600,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Yes": function() {
      window.location.replace("https://link_here");
    },
    No: function() {
      window.location.replace("https://link_here");
    }
  }
});
});
} );
```

When I remove the `$( "#order").click({` part of the jquery, it works as a popup for every link clicked, so the issue must be there but I am unable to solve.

Comment: did you use bootstrap or jquery UI?

Comment: I am using jquery UI

Comment: Why is there a on click being bound inside the properties of the dialog? That is a syntax error, hence why it works when you remove it. If you want it to show up on click, that you should be inisitalizing the dialog inside of the click.... `....on("click", function () { /* dialog code */ })` or call the method that makes it appear....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have calling dialog function before click
Please check below code

```js
$(function(){
            $('#order').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
                  resizable: true,
                  height: "auto",
                  width: 600,
                  modal: true,
                  buttons: {
                    "Yes": function() {
                      window.location.replace("https://link_here");
                    },
                    No: function() {
                      window.location.replace("https://link_here");
                    }
                  }
                });
            })
            
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
 <li><a href="#" id="order">Order </a></li>

<div id="dialog-confirm" style="display: none;"> 
<div class="message">UI Content goes here</div> 
<div class="buttons"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) add `autoOpen: false` to the dialog settings first, so popup won't be shown automatically on page load.

2) add click method on your link which will be showing the popup.

See this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4eo9w1cr/